# android MultiAutoCompleteTextView - displaying custom views in it

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, autosuggest

I'm implementing MultiAutoCompleteTextView with email contact suggestions. What i want to have is to display contact badges in the MultiAutoCompleteTextView content instead of strings. The Gmail Android app does it. 
Basically I Want what is shown in the drop down to be shown in the MultiAutoCompleteTextView (contact photo, name and email) after i typed in/selected the contact.
Is it possible?

[image: SSchot]

Comment: Clearly it is possible... it's in Gmail and the screenshot your posted... How about doing some research and trying something...?

Comment: The ssghot is from my app being developed. As You see the emails in EditText are strings, not pictures with strings as I want.

Comment: Ahhh you want that `View` you select to appear in the text box... I'm sure this is possible, but you will most likely need to create your own custom `EditText` to be able to hold images and/or text. I would try to dig up gmails source and see what they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google does this via using a custom ImageSpan. I just implemented this successfully for one of my apps. You should look at RecipientEditTextView.java to see how they do it. Essentially they create a drawable via Canvas and assign that drawable to a custom ImageSpan. I cannot post any code since ... well there is a ton, however you should get a good idea looking thru the source.